# Sublime text3 xdebug remote server

Tags: sublimetext3, xdebug

I’m trying to setup xdebug on my remote server to work with sublime text3.
 I already install the sublime text3 plugin, install xdebug on server and setup xdebug.ini but it's not working.
Can someone explain to me this process?

I'm using ssh plugin for sublime to sync remote project with local and I don't have a local address.

Here is my sublime xdebug User settings

```
{
"debug_layout" : {
"cols": [0.0, 0.3, 1.0],
"rows": [0.0, 0.8, 1.0],
"cells": [[0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2]]
},

// Group and index positions for debug views.
"context_index": 0,
"watch_index": 1,
"stack_index": 0,
"breakpoint_index": 1,

"breakpoint_group": 2,
"context_group": 1,
"stack_group": 2,
"watch_group": 1,

"path_mapping": {
"/path/on/server/project" : "/Users/user/my/local/project/"
},
"ide_key": "ls.xdebug"
}
```

And my xdebug.inizend_extension=xdebug.so

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 12.34.56.78 # this will be my address
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9005
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it is useful, this was my project file from when I last used it:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "/Users/antonis/Sites/demo"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "xdebug": {
             "url": "http://localhost:5080/",
        }
    }
}
```